# Stuck in first gear

Tags: toyota, manual-transmission, camry

I have a manual Toyota Camry . I find that I cannot get out of first gear when I go above 2000 rpm . It is stuck in first gear until I slow right down to 1000 revs . Then I can move into second gear.

The fluid in gear box has been drained and replaced.
The clutch is 6 mths old .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Two things to check: motor mounts & shifter linkage bushings.